# obter os 3 maiores números de uma lista em python

Tags: python, python-3.x

alguém pode me ajudar a encontrar o erro?

> """Returns a list of the three largest elements input_list in order from largest to smallest. If input_list has fewer than three elements, return input_list element sorted largest to smallest/"""

```
    # TODO: implement this function

    def top_three(input_list):
        list1 = [2,3,5,6,8,4,2,1]
        input_list = sorted(list1, reverse=True)
        return input_list[:3]
    print (top_three(1))
```

Comment: Por quê há este `[:2]` na chamada da função? Você não deveria passar a lista completa como parâmetro?

Comment: era para retornar os 3 primeiros números. Eu fiz uma nova função mas não sei onde está o erro:
def top_three(input_list):
    list1 = [2,3,5,6,8,4,2,1]
    input_list = sorted(list1, reverse=True)
    return input_list[:3]
print (top_three(1))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Heapq

Uma alternativa seria o uso de heapq:

```
import heapq  
lst = [2, 3, 5, 6, 8, 4, 2, 1]

# Os 3 maiores:
heapq.nlargest(3,lst)
[8, 6, 5]

# Os 3 menores
heapq.nsmallest(3,lst)
[1, 2, 2]
```

Comment: Valeu Sidon, mas tenho que usar a função para o objeto em questão.

Comment: Ok, é só usar heapq dentro da função, mas vou editar a resposta e colocar uma alternativa caso vc não possa usar heapq. Stay tuned. :-)

Comment: Na verdade ja estava na pergunta. Esquece.

Comment: Consegui com o código abaixo, vou pesquisar pela sua solução que parece ser melhor que a função para este tipo de parâmetro.

def top_three(input_list):
    input_list.sort()
    tops=input_list[-3:]
    q=sorted(tops, reverse=True)
    return q
    
list1 = top_three([2,3,5,6,8,4,2,1])
print (list1)

Answer (score 3):

Você tem dois problemas é aí . Um deles é justamente que você está limitando os dados da lista duas vezes: ao chamar a função, voĉe deve passar a sua lista completa, fora de ordem -e ela retornará os 3 maiores valores. Ao escrever a chamada a função como `top_three(input_list[:2]))` você está passando apenas os três primeiros valores da sua lista, na ordem em que se encontram. A função vai "enxergar" uma sub-ista com apenas esses três valores,e , obviamente, dizer que eles são os três maiores.

Agora outro problema aí é que você de fato não está usando o valor passado para a função - na primeira linha dentro da função `top_three` você faz `input_list = [2,3,5,6,8,4,2,1]`- e isso sobre-escreve a lista passada como parâmetro para a função - e ela vai funcioanr sempre com os mesmos números.

Comment: Obrigado @jsbueno, eu fiz os ajustes mas ainda estou tendo problemas com pois não consigo fazer o print retornar os 3 maiores números agora.

def top_three(input_list):
    list1 = [2,3,5,6,8,4,2,1]
    return sorted(list1, reverse=True)[input_list]
print (top_three[:2])

Comment: muito obrigado pela ajuda. Consegui a resposta dando uma pequena volta:
def top_three(input_list):
    input_list.sort()
    tops=input_list[-3:]
    q=sorted(tops, reverse=True)
    return q
    
list1 = top_three([2,3,5,6,8,4,2,1])
print (list1)

Answer (score 0):

Deu certo assim:

```
def top_three(input_list):
    input_list.sort()
    tops=input_list[-3:]
    q=sorted(tops, reverse=True)
    return q

list1 = top_three([2,3,5,6,8,4,2,1])
print (list1)
```